# Where does basictex install command line tools

Tags: command, latex

I'm interested in using LaTeX as I prepare my first scientific paper. I've installed [basictex](https://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) and have been using it through [texlive](https://www.google.com/search?q=texlive&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS671US671&oq=texlive&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j0l3.796j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I'd like to start using the basictex command line tools. I don't know where they are located or how *texlive* is able to magically find them.

What can I do?